# React Navigation custom bottom tabs Images

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a custom bottom tab navigation using the React Navigation v6, I'm providing Images as my icons for the bottom navigation, how can I provide dynamic Images in my `CustomTabBar`, currently I'm using one single Image for all my `Tab.Screen`, how is it that I can use or pass different images for each `Tab.Screen` ? also another thing what are the types of the props ? I'm ignoring the type error using the `@ts-ignore`, what is actually the types of the props.
I would appreciate if someone can help me with this, quite new to React Native :

This is `MyTabs.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/home/HomeScreen';
import NewsScreen from '../screens/news/NewsScreen';

// Define custom tab bar component
//@ts-ignore
function CustomTabBar({state, descriptors, navigation}) {
  return (
    <View
  style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2C2C2C',
    height: 100,
    width: '100%',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 60,
    borderTopRightRadius: 60,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
  }}>
  {/**@ts-ignore */}
  {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
    const {options} = descriptors[route.key];
    const label =
      options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
        ? options.tabBarLabel
        : options.title !== undefined
        ? options.title
        : route.name;
    const isFocused = state.index === index;

    const onPress = () => {
      const event = navigation.emit({
        type: 'tabPress',
        target: route.key,
      });

      if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
        navigation.navigate(route.name);
      }
    };

    const onLongPress = () => {
      navigation.emit({
        type: 'tabLongPress',
        target: route.key,
      });
    };

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        accessibilityRole="button"
        accessibilityState={isFocused ? {selected: true} : {}}
        accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
        testID={options.tabBarTestID}
        onPress={onPress}
        onLongPress={onLongPress}
        style={{padding: 8}}
        key={route.key}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/icons/homeIcon.png')}
          style={{
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            tintColor: isFocused ? '#2196F3' : '#666',
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  })}
    </View>
  );
}

// Define tab navigator
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
  <Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
  tabBar={props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({size, focused}) => (
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/icons/homeIcon.png')}
          style={{width: size, height: size}}
        />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="News"
    component={NewsScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({size, focused}) => (
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/icons/mapIcon.png')}
          style={{width: size, height: size}}
        />
      ),
    }}
  />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MyTabs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can setup different images for each tab

If ou pass a function to `Tab.Navigator's screenOptions prop`, it calls the function with an object, which contains a `route` object, which has a `name` param:

```
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={params => getOptionsForRoute(params)}>
```

Then you can create a function to answer differently to each call:

```
const getOptionsForRoute = ({route}) => {
    return {
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
            return <YourIconComponent route={route} focused={focused} />;
        },
    }
}
```

Then, you can create a component (`YourIconComponent`) that reads the route and focused props, and renders the correct icon for each situation (each tab and focused/unfocused states).

You can also return other params to change things like the label text, label styling etc. [Check all the possible options here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#options)